# Wordpress - sub term template file for taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type Service and in there have a number of terms and sub terms:

```
term 1
--sub term 1
--sub term 2 
term 2
--sub term 1
--sub term 2
```

I have using the template file taxonomy-service-tax.php to display the template of the term in custom post type and now i want to have a different template for sub term, so .. what template file should i use to display sub term page in custom post type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same template use 2 different files. Include one if your term doesn't have parent, user the other one if term does have parent term.

Comment: the taxonomy-service-tax.php file i already used to display all the sub term of the term, and i want when sub term is clicked, it will display all post of the sub term in different template... please help me to archieve that

Comment: I was trying to say that.... first check whether current taxonomy have any parent or not.  If your taxonomy doesn't have any parent use the code which you have already done (showing sub terms). Now if the term have parent the get the posts and show that. And to keep things clean get thsese two codes in 2 files and include them conditionally... WooCommerce also does the same type thing for product category and product but in  a reverse way. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed your instructions, then do some research based on your instructions and finally did it, thank you for your guidance.